# Column count does not work with css in PDF

Tags: css, node.js, pdf

I will used `column-count: 2;` and `columns:2;` in html and that html convert in pdf format.

I can use below npm package

```
npm install -g html-pdf
```

in pdf `column-count: 2;` not working

and I can try also this

```
@media print{
    .newspaper {
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
        -moz-column-gap: 20px;
        column-gap: 20px;
    }
}
```

but it's not working.

My requirement is first column fill up then start second column this is my main requirement.

Thanks

Comment: why do you mean by not working?